# cannot convert from 'string' to 'string[]'

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I am trying to write some code that will send an email to email addresses saved in a database. 
I have the code that finds the addresses but I get the error:

> cannot convert from 'string' to 'string[]'

```
string ToAddresses;
        DataSet ds = Company.GetCompany(Company.Current.CompanyID, Company.Current.CompCode);
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            ToAddresses = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FleetEmail"].ToString();
        }

        Utils.ChecklistSendMail("Checklist", ToAddresses, "body"); //error with ToAddresses
```

ChecklistSendMail function:

```
public static void ChecklistSendMail(string Subject, string[] ToAddresses, string Body)
        {
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailMsg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            if (ToAddresses != null)
            {
                foreach (string s in ToAddresses)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                    {
                        mailMsg.To.Add(s);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

how do I convert string to string[]?

Comment: Try `Utils.ChecklistSendMail("Checklist", new string[]{ ToAddresses}, "body");`

Comment: @YacoubMassad that worked thanks

Comment: You are sending a single string to a parameter which expects an array of string, what else you expect ? Are you sure you will only get a single string from the db ?

Comment: @Habib yes the email addresses are saved in a single string that will need to be separated by a semicolon. I haven't done the code for that yet

Comment: In that case use `String.Split` like `Utils.ChecklistSendMail("Checklist", ToAddresses.Split(';'), "body");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are sending a single string whereas your parameter expects an array of strings.

As you have indicated in your comments, that you have semicolon delimited emails as a single string value, you should `Split` your string based on semicolon and then use the return value as the parameter. `String.Split` will return a `string[]`. So your working code should be :

```
Utils.ChecklistSendMail("Checklist", ToAddresses.Split(';'), "body");
```